# php-gettext not working on windows

Tags: php, gettext

I'm trying to transalte my website, the problem is that I can't get `gettext()` to work this is my code:

```
$lang = 'esp';
putenv('LC_ALL='.$lang);
setlocale(LC_ALL, "esp");
bindtextdomain($lang, realpath('./locale'));
bind_textdomain_codeset($lang, 'UTF-8'); 
textdomain($lang);
echo _("Multilingual Web Applications with twig and php");
```

I've tried to see what each functions returns and they all seem to be working perfectly, but still I can't get the gettext function to work
here is my output:

Multilingual Web Applications with `twig` and `php`

Thanks

Comment: What do your apps locale files contain? You don't mention the process of translating that phrase.

Comment: Do you have a corresponding .mo file? Or are you expecting gettext() to just translate your English phrase into Spanish?

Comment: yes i have esp.mo file and esp.po that i've generated using poedit and they are stocked on this path /locale/esp/LC_MESSAGES/esp.mo

Comment: can you answer me please i really need your help thank you

Comment: I have the same problem. Sadly it is really not working on Windows.
However I found gettext alternative. 1. https://launchpad.net/php-gettext/ 2. https://github.com/oscarotero/Gettext